# Why can't I ask if hardware exists that does something, or fits a need?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics, on-topic

I can understand not wanting shopping questions: that is a comparison between two products that exist that relies on the subjective input of the person answering. But if I have a need, it seems I should be able to ask whether *any* product exists that satisfies that need.

- [Do any 4TB single-sided NVME drives exist?](https://superuser.com/questions/1714377/do-any-4tb-single-sided-nvme-drives-exist)

I don't understand why that question isn't on topic, it's explicitly about *computer hardware*, and it's not asking for a *recommendation*. Such a product either exists, or it doesn't. And any example of existence would answer the question.

Seems pretty basic user stuff, people will ask,

- Can I replace the hard drive in my laptop (frequently "no" these days).
- Does a replacement OEM hard drive with one that adds extra capacity (seems like the answer can also be "no").

Either way, if this is off topic it should be exluded in the FAQ,

- https://superuser.com/help/on-topic

And added to the list of things you should **not** ask, which right now only includes subjective answers.

- https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: We do have a sibling site that does hardware recommendations which your actual question "I need a big, single sided card" might fit. That you need it to fit is important, and probably worth adding if you're ok with TLC (most systems are) or QLC

Comment: Rather than asking if there is a technical reason why it would or would not be possible you are asking "does it exist". You do have a final part in your question asking how to go about finding the right part but it is overshadowed by "are there any that" coming across as "show me one that exists" and appearing as an attempt to skirt around the product recommendation request prohibition.

Answer (score 1):

Putting together the key points from your original question and your Meta question:

> Are there any NVME drives above 2TB that are one-sided?
>
> Such a product either exists, or it doesn't.
>
> And any example of existence would answer the question.

I'm a bit torn on this one, and it *might* be a bit of a gray area, but I do (somewhat reluctantly) agree with closing this one.

Ok, so you clearly aren't looking for a "yes or no" answer.  You're looking for an existence proof that would make it a "yes".  Alternatively, such a question could theoretically be answered by a technical reason why such a thing wouldn't or doesn't exist.

But by asking a question which you hope will be affirmatively answered by a product example, it seems to me to absolutely be:

> asking for a product, service or learning material recommendation

Note that "recommendations" aren't necessarily always (subjective) "endorsements".  They can also simply be objective statements that the product meets the requirement you've placed in your question.

But the real question is why this is a problem in your particular post.

The issue, as I see it, is that any "yes" answer that provides an example would be just as valid as any other example.  It may be an objective, "Yes, it meets that requirement."  But it's still open-ended with no one answer being "correct", or even "most correct".

That's biggest reason why shopping recommendations are off-topic here.

Some other Stack Exchange sites share similar restrictions.  Stack Overflow, for instance, prohibits requests for libraries that will meet a particular need.  Certainly, the question is objective, but there may be a (very) large number of examples that correctly answer the question.

On the other hand, I've noticed that Ask Ubuntu has no such restriction, and sometimes answer will run into the double-digits because of that.

The Super User community has clearly opted for prohibiting these types of questions, though.

Comment: You've pretty much got why I would leave the question closed. It is not asking "is this theoretically possible" but instead it is asking, in an oblique way, "does such a product exist" with an implication that the only way to prove it is to show a product. It feels like an attempt to skirt around asking for a product while making it sound like it isn't asking for us to go shopping.

Comment: To add onto this reason, any answer that  indicated that, “yes the product does exist” without a product model as evidence I personally wouldn’t find helpful. Because how do you say a product exists without saying a model or manufacture or a product line, in my opinion you can’t

Comment: I think this is an attempt to answer my question in a vacuum as if to say it's a _tad_ subjective. Which is true. It is a _tad_. But ZO MY FG this whole site.. https://superuser.com/questions/55927/download-all-flickr-sets-images "Download all flickr sets" has produced a ton of asnwers. There is nothing objective about that at all. And it'll keep on producing answers. Worse, it's awesome. I came looking for it. That's the problem. A bit of subjectivity serves the community **MUCH** better than reducing questions to Objective or Closed

Comment: @Mokubai Conversely, if it was asking if such a product could be created using the known laws of the universe, it would almost certainly _not_ be accepted here. This whole site is based on products which exist. You're literally serving a community of consumers united by products and services.

Comment: @EvanCarroll Asking *"How do I do <xyz>?"* and *"Is there a product that does <xyz>?"* are two different questions.  Yes, it's a bit odd that a product recommendation *could* answer either one, and the *answer* is allowed, but the second form of the question is not.  But the first can also often be answered, (preferably) with instructions/steps that don't require a separate download or product purchase.  There are also plenty of off-topic questions that don't get closed (and some on-topic that do get closed).  The Flickr question, for instance, is actually off-topic as a web app.